# jQuery (this) as succession of jQuery Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In this script, I'm fetching a load of data from a MySQL aray, and adding in a little favourite button on each array of returned data, the code for that is

```
...php while code to fetch array...
...more output...
<a class="favlink" id="'.$row['id'].'">favourite</a>
..more output...
```

and from that, I've used this bit of jQuery to run a PHP script:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $(".favlink").bind("click", function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: "v="+$(this).attr("id"),
            url: "fav.php",
            success: function(data) {
            alert('asf');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

That works fine, but what I actually want to do, is change the success to something like this:

```
success: function(data) {
$(this).html("<font color='#ccc'><a href='#'>favourited</a></font>");
}
```

And, that didn't work!

**Is there any way I can change the clicked favourite link to a different font color / and change the text from 'favourite' to 'favourited'?**

I assume the 'this' property is no longer 'this' on success for some reason, but I'm not sure?

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define the `context` of the `ajax`. See the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) from Jquery site:

> contextObject This object will be made the context of all Ajax-related
>   callbacks. By default, the context is an object that represents the
>   ajax settings used in the call ($.ajaxSettings merged with the
>   settings passed to $.ajax). For example specifying a DOM element as
>   the context will make that the context for the complete callback of a
>   request, like so:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
    $(this).addClass("done");
  }
});
```

So in your's case I think this is what you need:

```
  $.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: this,//OR: $(".favlink")[0], // Depends on your scope.
  success: function(){
      $(this).html("<font color='#ccc'><a href='#'>favourited</a></font>");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line to the `$.ajax` parameters. By default the context is linked to the `$.ajaxSettings` of the request. Setting the below line changes the context of `this` in the ajax request to equal that of the calling method.

```
context: this,
```

So your new code will look like this:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $(".favlink").bind("click", function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: "v="+$(this).attr("id"),
            url: "fav.php",
            context: this,
            success: function(data) {
                $(this).html("<font color='#ccc'><a href='#'>favourited</a></font>");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! :) Didn't realize there was a context parameter!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $('.favlink').click(function() { // this may match more than one element
        var $this = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            'type': 'GET',
            'data': 'v=' + this.id,
            'url': 'fav.php',
            'success': function(data) {
                $this.html('whatever you want');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

You could also use the `context` parameter for `jQuery.ajax`, but I personally think this (hah!) is more readable.